# Preventing users from getting access to an admin login page

Tags: php, security

Currently I am setting up an admin login page with PHP and this is how I have it set up.

If the user navigates to website.com/admin, it returns a 404 error. The only way to get access to the admin login is to go to website.com/admin?key=random-string. If the key in the URL doesn't match the key in the database it will return a 404 error. When the key matches it will present you with the admin login.

I thought this was clever to help prevent someone from getting access to the admin login screen, but I am not experienced enough to know if this is true.

Comment: What is your question? Whether or not that's secure? Not really.

Comment: no less safe than asking for a password

Comment: Essentially that is my question. I don't know of a way to 100% hide the login page or if it is even possible. Once the key in the URL matches the key in the Database, they still need to provide a valid username and password. I figured it was an extra step in the verification process to make it that much more difficult to get access to the admin controls.

Comment: its called obsfication, really it adds nothing over your requirement of username\password but if you want to do it -go for it.

Comment: My thought process was this: If someone wants to try and guess the admin password, they would first need to know the key to see the login screen. If they hacked the database to get the key, they would still be out of luck because the key is hashed and uniquely salted.

Comment: Every new layer of security is certainly an improvement and obfuscation is one tool you could use in the process, as long as you are using many other tools.  As you probably already know, there is no such thing as an unbreakable security system, but making it more difficult couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought this was clever to help prevent someone from getting access
>   to the admin login screen, but I am not experienced enough to know if
>   this is true.

Do not try and defeat an attacker by trying to outwit them. Always assume attackers are clever than you are, and build your security on that model.

Make your login and session management system is provably secure instead. For example:

- Employ two factor authentication.
- Use HTTPS along with Secure cookies and HSTS.
- Rate limit or lock accounts after a number of failed logins.
- Make sure you are not vulnerable to session fixation.
- Make sure you are not vulnerable to user enumeration.

Checkout the [Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) for some more pointers.

Also, don't use secrets in the URL itself. Even though these are protected if HTTPS is used, they are logged in browser and proxy history, by server logs by default, and can be leaked in `referer` headers.

Answer (score 2):

For an extra layer of security you are better off using htaccess and htpassword for the /admin directory. There are several tutorials and generators available.

This way when browsing to the page it will ask for a password/key. If it is entered correctly it will show your login page - else it will show a forbidden error.

Comment: So you think I should add the htaccess/htpassword in addition to what I have set up now or to replace what I have now? This was my initial idea, but I felt like if someone looking to do harm found this page that was protected with htaccess/htpassword, they would know I was trying to hide something and now the exact directory they would need to target. With my set up now, they would just get a 404 and think I had the admin side of things set up elsewhere and not think anything of it.

Comment: As long as you are using SSL and your script is secure this should be adequate. To go an extra step you could rename /admin to something random and make sure it is not indexed. No system is 100% secure, but having to guess/scan for a random directory, followed by a (long) key, followed by a username and (strong) password should give you reasonable protection. If you have fail2ban or csf/lfd setup and configured on your server these can block brute force attempts. You could even integrate blocking in your script if there are multiple incorrect logins - it all depends how far you want to go.

Comment: Okay. I was thinking about renaming /admin to something else like /pinkbutterflies that is random but still rememberable to me. The data in my database isn't sensitive by any means. I have no user logins, no addresses, no phone numbers or emails, just content for the website so I don't need anything over the top. I realize people do like to cause havoc just for the fun of it, so I want to to be somewhat secure to prevent some jackass from brute forcing into the admin page and deleting everything making the website practically useless. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you please vote for it.